# Aplicação que não precise carregar página inteira

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Como posso criar uma aplicação em `MVC C#` com `Razor`, onde eu tenho um Layout e então só atualize o conteúdo central e não a página como um todo.

Li alguns lugares para usar `AJAX` outro pra usar `PartialView`. Porém qual o melhor método? E como fazer isso?

Comment: você vai usar `AJAX` com `PartialView`

Comment: tem algum exemplo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você deverá utilizar algo da seguinte forma

No seu `controller` você deve definir uma action que retornará o que você precisa

```
public class HomeController : Controller

    public ActionResult Index() {
       return View();
    } 

    //...


    public ActionResult Detalhes() {
       return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Na sua página(`view`) você deve escolher um lugar(`div`) para receber o resultado via `ajax`

**index.cshtml** (view da Action Index)

```
@{ Layout ="../Shared/_Layout.cshtml" } 
<!-- conteúdo da minha index -->
<!-- e quero atualizar apenas uma parte dentro da minha view index.cshtml com o retorno da partial Detalhes -->
<div id="detalhes"></div>
```

No seu `javascript\jQuery` você fará uma requisição `ajax` para o `controller` e colocará o resultado nessa div:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/Home/Detalhes",
    success: function(data) {
       $("#detalhes").html(data);
    }
});
```

ou da maneira reduzida

```
$.get("/home/detalhes", function(data) {
    $("#detalhes").html(data);
});
```

Nesse caso, nem altero a `_Layout.cshtml`, não removo o `@RenderBody` porque o conteúdo da *index.cshtml* será jogado dentro do layout onde estava ele e que por sua vez, na minha index, irá ter uma area que receberá um conteúdo da action `detalhes` sem ter que recarregar toda a página.

**Extra:**

Se você já tiver uma `PartialView` que por convensão se nomeia com o `underscore\underline` na frente (ex: `_SouUmaPartialView`), você poderá renderizar ela em outras páginas ao iniciar as páginas (porque ela é reutilizável) da seguinte maneira.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_SouUmaPartialView.cshtml", seuObjetoCasoNecessarioPassarDados);
```

Comment: No layout eu mudaria o  @RenderBody(), por <div id="detalhes"></div>. E então na View eu adicionaria o ajax? Fiquei um pouco confuso :S

Comment: Fiz um update com uma atualização da resposta, vê se deu para entender agora

Comment: Tem como eu não usar o @RenderBody()? Por exemplo o index ser igual o detalhes? Logo sendo uma partialview do layout?

Comment: O @RenderBody() caso você queira não utilizar, você terá que repetir todo o html em suas páginas. A sua index.cshtml é como se fosse já uma partialview que é inserida onde está o @RenderBody() .... dá uma olhada nesse link que explica como trabalhar com Layouts: http://robsoncastilho.com.br/2011/06/04/asp-net-mvc-3-layout-pages-com-razor/

Answer (score 3):

Exemplo chamando a `PartialView` `Listagem`

#### Controller

```
public class Home
{
    public ActionResult Listagem()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

#### JavaScript

Com `jQuery`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/Listagem",
    success: function(retorno) {
        $("#minha-div").html(retorno); // Lança o HTML retornado na DIV de id `minha-div`
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você quer criar uma estrutura 'master page' para um projeto MVC com Razor.

Se for realmente esta a tua dúvida, Você pode criar uma página .cshtml que será seu Layout, e onde você desejar renderizar o conteúdo 'dinâmico' de seu site coloque o código @RenderBody();

Nas demais páginas do seu projeto onde você deseja herdar o código de seu Layout, utilize o código @{ Layout = "Caminho do seu Layout.cshtml"}

Exemplo:

**Layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <article class="container">
                <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </article>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>FOOTER</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Em uma outra página qualquer:**

```
@{
    Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

//Seu código com Razor aqui;
```

Comment: Realmente renderiza, mas ele quer realizar o `invoke` via Ajax